# Push notification doesn't reach in app for the first time

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification

I have a ios app with push notifications. When testers install the app for the first time in his device(active state) and receive a notification it arrives in the tray at the top. If I remove the app from background now and receive any new notification I receive it in didReceiveRemoteNotification delegate method and able to do my custom operation based upon this.
For the first time installation, I am getting this problem.
As per my understanding notification should not come in the tray at the top when the app is open. But I am getting it.

Comment: i think that behavior is since iOS 10

Comment: yes, I am testing it in iOS 10.3. Is this default behavior?

Comment: it's been a while out there. you can check [Why push notification is shown when app is foreground? iOS10 / iPhone 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40906057/why-push-notification-is-shown-when-app-is-foreground-ios10-iphone-7), [Push notification issue with iOS 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39490605/push-notification-issue-with-ios-10)